# How to list all users that have grants over a package

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I'm looking for some query to list all users that have grants over a package.

For example, user Schema_A has been granted to execute package: B.MyPackage.

I'm querying views or tables like: role_tab_privs, role_sys_privs,sys.dba_sys_privs, dba_role_privs... but I can't find what I'm looking.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the privilege has been granted directly or to a role, the grant will appear in `DBA_TAB_PRIVS`

```
SELECT grantee, privilege
  FROM dba_tab_privs
 WHERE owner = 'B'
   AND table_name = 'MYPACKAGE'
   AND privilege = 'EXECUTE'
```

If the `grantee` is a role, you would then need to look at `dba_role_privs` to see what users (or roles) have been granted that role and follow the chain if you have roles granted to other roles.  If you need to account for users that have grants because of the (very dangerous) `ANY` grants (i.e. `EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE`), that would require a separate query.

If you want to get more sophisticated than simply doing a straight query against `dba_tab_privs`, though, you are probably better off using on of [Pete Finnigan's scripts](http://www.petefinnigan.com/tools.htm) like the `who_has_priv.sql` (or `who_has_priv_procedure.sql`).  Pete is probably the leading expert on Oracle security so these are much more likely to account for every possible corner case than anything I would attempt to cobble together.